# arcgis maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, arcgis

I am trying to put an arcgis WMTS tile layer on top of openstreetmaps WMTS layer in flutter using the flutter_map plugin.
Here is my code :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: FlutterMap(
    options: new MapOptions(
      center: LatLng(33.8, 9.5),
      zoom: 6.0,
      pinchZoomWinGestures: MultiFingerGesture.pinchZoom,
    ),
    layers: [
      //layer 1 - leaflet tiles
      TileLayerOptions(
        urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        tileProvider: NonCachingNetworkTileProvider(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),

      //Layer 2 - leaflet tiles
      TileLayerOptions(
        urlTemplate:
            "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/C8EMgrsFcRFL6LrL/arcgis/rest/services/GEBCO_contours/MapServer/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}",
        subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        tileProvider: NonCachingNetworkTileProvider(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

but the arcgis map does not align correctly with the openstreetmap.

[as shown in the scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rDOo.jpg)

I hope you can help me rectify my code and have a great day

Answer (score 0):

I've faced something like this before. I was putting ArcGIS tile on top of Mapbox, and the result was like you described.

Probably the axes differ a little if the layers are made by Esri products.
And for this case, I only have 2 solutions for you :

1 - Use ArcGIS Pro or any ArcGIS tool and try shifting the layers till they fit the OpenStreetMap.

2 - Instead of using OpenStreetMap, use ArcGIS APIs, but you have to add some native code for iOS and Android, and check pub.dev for ArcGIS libraries.

Comment: Thank you for your respomd but what do you mean by add native code for IOS and android? Does the map render differently in each OS? And i did check pud.dev for arcgis libraries but they are outdated and does not fix this(flutter_map_arcgis plugin)

Comment: And i tried using both tiles from arcgis but still the same now even the base map is not aligned, it seems like the tile blocks are rotated

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced the similar issue with the ArcGIS map - it is not aligning correctly in the screen. The below pattern (*{z}/{y}/{x}*) renders the esri tiles correctly on the screen.

```
https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}
```